# Embed image into HTML Body in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook, outlook-2013

I am trying to create an email from an HTML file with images in the email body. These images are not hosted online and so I want the images to be embedded in the email (the original source is local).

Encoding as a base64 string has not worked, and I have tried the solution from this thread
[How to embed an image into an Outlook HTML email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688495/how-to-embed-an-image-into-an-outlook-html-email-message) with no luck either.

I also only care about the image displaying in outlook.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 2 options for images in email, and you've mentioned both in your OP.

Assuming you want to keep hammering away at the Base64 embedded images technique, here are a few resources:

- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email
- [How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)
- http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html

In the Campaign Monitor link there is a support chart - not sure if Outlook 2013 is unsupported all together, or if it just blocks the image like a linked hosted one, but either way it looks like there is no solution for automatically showing embedded images in Outlook 2013.