# how to embed multiple images into HTML email

Tags: html, email, newsletter

i need to embed multiple images inside an HTML email
[i found some old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)

but  i'm not sure how to write the boundary code, and if can have any value

```
--boundary-example
```

how can i test my file?
how can i send the generated code?
is it still the best way to use the CID method over embed base64 images?

i know that the best way would be to link images but client asked me not to do it

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688495/how-to-embed-an-image-into-an-outlook-html-email-message

Comment: the problem is that i don't have outlook i can do something similar with apple mail