# How to embed image (absolute path) in an HTML e-mail?

Tags: jakarta-mail, html-email, mime-message

I am trying to add Image with its absolute path to HTML email. When I give the image path src in the email body it is not working in outlook. is there any better way to add an image with its absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688495/how-to-embed-an-image-into-an-outlook-html-email-message) will help to you. 
**TL;DR** 
You have to attach the image and refer to it.
*(I will continue this answer soon)*